# What words/structures indicate an argument? (e.g. Therefore, as a result, there's strong reason to believe (x) , etc.)

Tags: grammar

To me, once of the most important parts of learning a language is the ability to read the implied message behind someone's words, and part of that is knowing when they're making a point and they're just shooting the breeze and explaining things. I know of a few, like から and ので, but does anyone have insight to offer, in this respect?

Comment: I think this question might be a little too broad. Basically you're just asking for a list of grammatical structures and phrases that indicate rhetoric. The best you'll get is a few examples rather than an exhaustive list which provides a full answer to your question, if such an answer is even possible. Have you tried looking through grammar references?

Comment: I have, and there are several volumes on the subject in my collection.  I would also, however, like to add to my database, so I can gives others samples,so they can zero in specific points in what someone's saying, and form an appropriate response, in addition to getting the ball rolling on learning future structures

Answer (score 3):

I guess these might fit your description they are phrases you would say when arguing.

```
それで - and that's why...
だったら - If that's the case then...
かと言って - but even so...
強いて言えば - If I had to say...
となると - If that's the case then...
それにしても - Even so...
いずれにしても - In any case...
というわけで - In conclusion...
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that these don't necessarily follow a general pattern, so it's worth mentioning a few more:

- つまるところ・つまり - In other words/to sum up
- 要するに・と - basically/what you're trying to say is
- 必ずしも〜というわけではない - It is not necessarily the case that ~
- どちらにせ・何にしろ　and all of the equivalent phrasings - Either way
- あえて言えば - One could go so far as to say...

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this question is probably too broad.  But here are a couple examples I can think of off the top of my head.

> - したがって
> - （した／という）結果で
> - なぜ（なら／かというと）